# Duplicating character strings in R

Tags: r, string

I am simulating some random DNA strings (sequences) in R. These sequences are composed of the letters A, C, G and T.

In a dataset of such sequences, some may be identical (duplicates).

Suppose I have 100 such sequences, which can be grouped in 5 unique sets.

Working code that I now have (shown below) will output something like

```
      Unique groups: 1   2  3  4  5
Number of Sequences: 96  1  1  1  1
```

However, I would like the distribution to be something like

```
         Unique groups: 1   2   3   4  5
   Number of Sequences: 56  24  10  5  5
```

This can be accomplished through randomly allocating some sequences from group 1 (96 sequences) to all other groups containing only a single sequence.

My sequences are stored in a variable called 'res'.

The below code doesn't quite do what I would like.

```
res <- res[sample(unique(nrow(res)), size = nrow(res), replace = TRUE), ]
```

In the above code, 'size' is the number of DNA sequences in the dataset.

How can the above code be altered to accomplish what I am needing?

Note: one does not know the number of unique sets that will be generated a priori, so using the 'probs' argument in sample will not suffice.

## Reproducible example:

```
library(pegas)
num.seqs <- 100 # number of DNA sequences to generate
length.seqs <- 500 # length of DNA sequences
mu.rate <- 1e-4 # mutation rate

set.seed(1234) # for reproducibility

nucl <- as.DNAbin(c('a','c','g','t')) # DNA alphabet

res <- sample(nucl, size = length.seqs, replace = TRUE, prob = rep(0.25, 4)) # generate a random DNA sequence

mu.set <- list('a' = as.DNAbin('c'),
           'a' = as.DNAbin('g'),
           'a' = as.DNAbin('t'),
           'c' = as.DNAbin('a'),
           'c' = as.DNAbin('g'),
           'c' = as.DNAbin('t'),
           'g' = as.DNAbin('a'),
           'g' = as.DNAbin('c'),
           'g' = as.DNAbin('t'),
           't' = as.DNAbin('a'),
           't' = as.DNAbin('c'),
           't' = as.DNAbin('g'))

muts <- function(res) {
  unlist(mu.set[as.character(res)])
}

duplicate.seq <- function(res) { # duplicate sequrnce
  num.muts <- rbinom(n = 1, size = length.seqs, prob = mu.rate) # add random mutations
  if (num.muts > 0) {
    idx <- sample(length.seqs, size = num.muts, replace = FALSE)
    res[idx] <- muts(res[idx])
  }
  res
}

res <- matrix(replicate(num.seqs, duplicate.seq(res)), byrow = TRUE, nrow =     num.seqs) # generate num.seqs sequences

class(res) <- "DNAbin"

h <- sort(haplotype(res), decreasing = TRUE, what = "frequencies") # distribution of unique groups
rownames(h) <- 1:nrow(h)

h # print distribution
```

## A simpler example (sans R package)

```
num.seqs <- 10
length.seqs <- 10

lets <- letters[c(1, 3, 7, 20)] # DNA alphabet
lets

res <- t(replicate(num.seqs, sample(lets, length.seqs, replace = TRUE))) # generate sequences
res <- res[sample(nrow(res), size = nrow(res), replace = TRUE), ] # duplicate some sequences
```

Comment: You can use `probs` in `sample`

Comment: @akrun True, but in reality, 'probs' is not known a priori because one does not know the number of unique sets that will be generated. I will add this caveat to my post.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want, I would recommend that you give a small 100% reproducible example with expected output

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks. I have added a reproducible example. Could you take a look?

Comment: You lost me at `library(pegas)` and `list('a'=as.DNAbin('c'),'a'=as.DNAbin('g'),...)`.

Comment: Are you able to simplify the example to something that doesn't involve DNA sequences, but instead just sequences of letters to demonstrate what you're looking for?

Comment: @r2evans 'pegas' is the R package that generates the DNA sequences 'under the hood' Type 'res' after running the code and a summary of the sequences will be outputted.

Comment: @brittenb I think what I have and what you propose are the exact same thing, except that it wouldn't involve the 'pegas' package.

Comment: And that's the key distinction. Asking us to install packages and use new functions that we're not familiar with complicates the approach for helping. If you're able to provide a relatively similar example without relying on those packages and functions, then that's better.

Comment: I don't mind installing a new package to answer a question but from where I am it takes ages, also I'm not sure if you've included an expected output. Examples that don't require a package also make the question more useful for next readers as they will certainly not install it :).

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I've added a simpler example (without package). Though, I'm uncertain how to get the distribution of unique sequences.

Comment: @brittenb See the updated post for a simpler (though incomplete) example

Comment: JarrettPhillips my point was not that I don't understand what the package is. I said "lost" because the problem is about basic string sampling and controlled replication, and I choose to not install arbitrary (for me) packages (and whatever baggage they impose, e.g., more packages: `ape` and `adegenet`) to help. Both brittenb and Moddy_Mudskipper discussed the same point, and your additional example is more on-point and generic, thank you for the revision.